# Intro guide to troubleshooting errors in clisp

Tags: clisp

I'm new to lisp, working in clisp on cygwin. When I have a problem, I see something like this

```
*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable DB.CLISP has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of DB.CLISP.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for DB.CLISP.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
Break 1 [4]
```

And I have a bunch of prompts where the number seems to increment no matter what I do.

Can someone point me to a newbie guide to what this does, and what I can do here? I've found a few things but they are opaque to me. My practice now is just to quit out of clisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take look at [clisp faq list](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html)?

It has a question you are asking: *How do I get out of the debugger?*, although it links to the wrong section of the manual, what you are looking for is [Top Level Loop](http://clisp.org/impnotes/repl.html).

Basically, "abort" reduces the debug level by 1 and "quit" drops you out of all the debuggers.